# How to use the conversationhandler to get user inputs in Python (python-telegram-bot)

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Hi so I am fairly new with using the python-telegram-bot thus I am not so sure how to add the ConversationHandler function into my telegram bot:

my idea is that I want to use see if my bot is able to print out the calendar for a given month and year that the user inputs (I know that I have to use the calendar module for this). Here is my code so far (I know it is atrocious sorry :/)

```
from telegram.ext import ConversationHandler 
def calendar(update,context):
    update.message.reply_text('Input month and year')


#Unsure what command to type next such that bot is able to receive necessary input for month & year to print out
```

here is my main command:

```
updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY, use_context = True )
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("calendar", calendar_command)) 
updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Please help me with this I have been googling around and am still unsure how this whole thing works :') any help is more than appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't really specified where exactly you're stuck/which part of `ConversationHandler` is unclear to you, I can only give some general hints:

- Make sure to read the documentation of [`ConversationHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html)
- There are examples in the [examples directory](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#conversationbotpy) of `python-telegram-bot` that can give you a first impression of how `ConversationHandler` can be used. Running the example while trying to follow the logic in the code simultanuously can help a lot.
- If you want to understand the general idea of `ConversationHandler` more thoroughly: It's basically a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`